# AWK add line below a search pattern with variable and in a shell script

Tags: macos, bash, shell, awk

theres a little problem with using an awk line in a shell script and I can't find the misstake I made. Hope, anybody can help me.

I use awk version 20070501 and Mac.

I am using the following code to add a line under a specified pattern:

```
...

ANSHOSTGROUPS=($(egrep "^\[.*\]$" hosts))
INSERT="dc01.fritz.box ansible_ssh_host=192.168.4.27"
...
awk -v INSERT=$INSERT "/${ANSHOSTGROUPS[2]}/{print \$1;print INSERT;next}1" hosts > /tmp/tmp_hosts && mv -f /tmp/tmp_hosts hosts
```

I get the following in the file "hosts":

```
[test]
centos7-test.fritz.box

[lab]
dc01.fritz.box ansible_ssh_host=192.168.4.27

[ldap]
dc01.fritz.box ansible_ssh_host=192.168.4.27

[mysql]
dc01.fritz.box ansible_ssh_host=192.168.4.27
```

Now when I use the following for testing directly on the command line:

```
awk -v INSERT="dc01.fritz.box ansible_ssh_host=192.168.4.27" "/\[ldap\]/{print \$1;print INSERT;next}1" hosts
```

I correctly get

```
[test]
centos7-test.fritz.box

[lab]

[ldap]
dc01.fritz.box ansible_ssh_host=192.168.4.27

[mysql]
```

Thanks all for your help!

--- edit here because the comment field is too small

Ok, I used the file content in my question to build the variable.
I now used

```
ANSHOSTGROUPS=($(egrep "^\[.*\]$" hosts |sed 's/\[/\\\[/g' |sed 's/\]/\\\]/g'))
```

or just use

```
ANSHOSTGROUPS=(\[test\] \[lab\] \[ldap\] \[mysql\])
```

for testing without the need to build the file first.

Now the variable shows this:

```
echo ${ANSHOSTGROUPS[@]}
\[test\] \[lab\] \[ldap\] \[mysql\]
```

Next I tried to use your line: `awk -v anshostgroup="${ANSHOSTGROUPS[2]}" -v insert="dc01.fritz.box ansible_ssh_host=192.168.4.27" '$0 ~ anshostgroup{$0=$1 ORS insert}1' hosts`

After that I got the same false output I wrote in my question. I also tried to build the variable without the two pipes and sed. But same output.

Comment: You are trying to use a shell variable in awk `${ANSHOSTGROUPS[2]`

Comment: What do you see when you use `bash -x yourscript.sh`?  Specifically, is the correct value substituted into the `awk` script?    The manual code has a backslash in front of the regex metacharacter `[` (and a less crucial one in front of `]`).  Your `awk` script doesn't have that protection; it simply looks for lines that contain any letter from `[ldap]` (so an `a` _or_ a `d` _or_ an `l` _or_ a `p`).  At minimum, you need to put `\\${ANSHOSTGROUPS[2]}` in the `awk` script.  That may be sufficient.

Comment: I'm at work at the moment. I'll check that in the evening but you're right. Could be the `[` . Seems logical. I'll see if I can get the brackets out of the variable.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, I've found the misstake with your help. I've just changed `ANSHOSTGROUPS=($(egrep "^\[.*\]$" hosts))` to `ANSHOSTGROUPS=($(egrep "^\[.*\]$" hosts |sed 's/\[/\\\[/g' |sed 's/\]/\\\]/g'))` . As you said, the awk used the letters inside the `[]` as regular expression. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

The awk script you included in your answer should instead be:

```
awk -v insert="$INSERT" -v anshostgroup="${ANSHOSTGROUPS[2]}" '$0 ~ anshostgroup{$0=$1 ORS insert}1' hosts > /tmp/tmp_hosts && mv -f /tmp/tmp_hosts hosts
```

I changed your awk variable names to lower case as all-upper-case is for builtin names like `FS` and `RS`. You should not be using all-upper-case shell names either as by convention that's just for exported variables.

If you posted some testable sample input and expected output we could help you get the rest of the script right too (you do NOT need grep+sed+2 pipes but without seeing the sample input I'm not going to try to figure out the right way to try to parse it!).

Comment: Thanks for your help so far. I'm still learning and glad for any help. I'll test the line.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works now within the shell script. Thanks to Jonathan Leffler!!

```
...

ANSHOSTGROUPS=($(egrep "^\[.*\]$" hosts |sed 's/\[/\\\[/g' |sed 's/\]/\\\]/g'))
INSERT="dc01.fritz.box ansible_ssh_host=192.168.4.27"
...
awk -v INSERT=$INSERT "/${ANSHOSTGROUPS[2]}/{print \$1;print INSERT;next}1" hosts > /tmp/tmp_hosts && mv -f /tmp/tmp_hosts hosts
```

Just in case anybody is interested in the full script to use or modify it: https://github.com/matze502/scripts/tree/master/bash/vmware/fusion

I use the script to automatically clone a vm for lab use with vmware fusion.

Comment: That is absolutely NOT how to do it as it complicates your awk script be needeing to escape `$` signs, etc and creates all sorts of opportunities for bizarre failures and/or error messages since you are making the contents of a shell variable part of the awk script text rather than setting an awk variable to the contents of the shell variable.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you have a better idea to get it to work, then I'm open for all. I just found out that this is the only way for me to get this task done. Maybe I can also use `-v ANSHOSTGROUPS=${ANSHOSTGROUPS[2]}`

Comment: I just posted an answer for that part of the script.